# Azure SQL database still incurring vcore charges despite move to DTU?

Tags: azure, azure-sql

So, in my MSDN subscription, myself and a developer set up an Azure SQL 480mb database to test performance, initially on the vcore model. Charges very quickly accrued and despite practically nothing being done with the database beyond the initial load and a couple of performance tests, we were at the £17 mark within a day or two! Yikes.. so we experimented with Basic DTU, Standard S0 and S1 and settled on S1 9DTU20) as being ideal. Today, I log in to the portal to find my vcore (gen5) charges have more than doubled to nearly £34! This is despite nobody using it at all (the developer was on leave, and I was busy elsewhere).

Can anyone advise what's going on here?

```
single general purpose - serverless - compute gen5    vcore £33.68
single standard                                     s0 dtus £ 2.44
single standard                                     s1 dtus £ 1.46
single/elastic pool general purpose - storage   data stored £ 0.14
single basic                                         b dtus £ 0.01
```

You can clearly see our changes/trials with basic, S0 and S1 (settled on S1)- so why is vcore still increasing as well?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, unless you are using the serverless version of SQL, whether anyone is using it or not is irrelevant. So long as the database exists you will be charged for it.

I would imagine that the additional cost is from when you had it in vCore mode, costs can take a day or two to flow through. If you don't agree with the cost then you would need to raise a billing ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Sam - I wondered if it was just that costs hadn't flown all the way through. Will monitor over the next day or two and see what happens, see if the vcore increases any. vCore costs seem astronomical tho - that was it practically on the lowest spec, and £33 in just a couple days isn't sustainable..

Comment: The cheapest vCore price is $390 per month, these prices are not dynamic and apply so long as you have the DB running so it should be easy to calculate what you cost will be upfront. vCore specs are designed for workloads that need that amount of CPU and Memory, so if you don't need that then look at cheaper DTU model, that is what it is for. You can also look at the serverless option if you only want to pay per use. It's all relative, £33 a day is nothing for a demanding app that needs that level of performance.

Comment: So, what happened today - I logged in, and those vcore charges had wiped back to the cost it was 3 days ago before I moved to DTU. Am guessing this was actually a billing error.

Thanks for the input on the vcore model tho Sam, that was really helpful.